# Acces second router configuration

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I have 2 wireless routers:

WAN --> Router1 --> Router2

`My PC` is currently connected to `Router1`

All connections are wired. `Router1` is a TP-Link TL-WR841N; `Router2` is an ASUS.

I need to configure the second router using `My PC`.

So, I've accesed `Router1`'s configuration page and found the `192.168.0.103` IP address assigned to the second router.

I should acces `192.168.1.1` to configure `Router2` if I would have been connected to it.

How can I manage second router without direct connection to it?

Comment: You should be able to connect to both routers from your PC using their corresponding IP if they are wired as in your diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, Router 2 has 'remote management' disabled. Normally you connect the WAN port on Router 2 to a 'real' internet connection, so Router 2 will see any data coming from that port as 'external internet'. Normally you don't want to expose the default username and password to the entire internet as that is generally bad.

So, to keep Grandma secure on her default internet setup, manufacturers will disable remote management for routers as their default settings.

What you need to do is hook a computer directly to the LAN or WLAN on Router 2 and then connect to the management interface from there. Once in the settings panel look for 'Remote Management' and enable it. Be sure to change the password to something long.

Once this is set up you will be able to connect to Router2 via its address given by Router 1, in your case `192.168.0.103`.